# GeoJSON layer shows/enables only one row in attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geojson, filter

I have a GeoJSON polygon layer which I converted from a shapefile layer. The layer opens up in [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/), for example, with no problem, displays the table correctly, etc:

[image: geojson_image]

However, in QGIS the Attribute Table only shows one polygon, with `"Features Total:146, Filtered:1, Selected:0"`, see the image below

[image: QGIS_image]

I've tried to remove this `"filter"`, using SQL to select all the polygons or just a couple of the polygons, then export selected, and still, I only get this one unit, 146.

How can I get QGIS to display the whole attribute table in GeoJSON and other formats?

One caveat: the original shapefile had a "lock" file on it. I don't have this problem when I export to `.shp`, though if I try to select polygons and export a subset of the original shapefile in any format, I run into the same problem.

Comment: I just tried a random GeoJSON, works fine for me, both QGIS and [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/). Can you please tell how your GeoJSON was achieved, where did you perform that conversion from shapefile into GeoJSON?

Comment: Are you sure there is no filter on the attribute table?  Try choosing "show all features" below the attribute table

Comment: I converted it using QGIS - Export - Save Features as, etc. I've done this hundreds of times with hundreds of files but for some reason this is the result I get, every time, when i convert this particular file. And I did choose "show all features", I selected all the features and then attempted to save selected for geojson, with the same result. It will only retain the attribute table if saved to SHP as a whole. Total mystery to me. The only thing i haven't tried is to open it in Arc convert and export, but my student license just ran out :/

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with a GeoJSON file (coincidentally with 146 features as well). Without any filters applied, the attribute table still shows "Total: 146, Filtered: 140". As a workaround, save as something else, e.g. GPKG.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably caused by having the same value in the ID field. Although GeoJSON doesn't require a unique ID, QGIS may be getting tripped up by the fact your layer doesn't have one. Try using field calculator to update the ID field (add @row_number) and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

I went back to the original shapefile and removed the .lock file, this solved the problem. I guess it corrupted the data when I converted it to geojson.

Comment: This doesn't add up. Were you looking at the same GeoJSON file in geojson.io as in QGIS? If so, it would have already been completely divorced from the original shapefile.